# an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file on nginx what is limiting the memory?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I use nginx as a reverse proxy.

From time to time, especially on large files and mjpeg streams, the warning message `an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file` is displayed.

What could be limiting the nginx memory usage ?

- I use docker-compose to start nginx: but by default the container
  uses all memory available.
- There is no nginx directive to change the
  default memory behaviour.

I could solve this by setting proxy_cache_path to /dev/shm but I want to understand what is limiting nginx memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens with **Nginx + PHP-FPM** and **Laravel** and you use **[Public File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem)**, the [solution](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk) is:

```
php artisan storage:link
```